# Fix a single Web parts width

Tags: 2013, branding

How can I fix the width of a specific webpart using css or otherwise, so that it doesn't expand if the browser is maximized and without it affecting other we parts in the same zone?

Setting the webpart to fixed width thru the OOTB GUI only stops content wrapping if the browser width reduces?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the inspector in chrome (or your favorite browser) you are able to see the ID of the webpart you want to customize. In my case I´ve got the id of `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4`. In that case you can use the css:

`#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4{
  width:500px`}

That will make the webpart fiksed with a 500px width. Or you kan use the css property of `max-width` it all depends...

If you can add some information about what you want to do, I´m more than happy to update my answer with a more customized css for you. You also have to remember that the id of the web part will change if you remove it and add it again, in that case, simply just update your css. Or write another selector from a parent html element.

Comment: @Razzmos, can you mark the question as answered?

Edit: good to know it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to wrap the web part zone in your page layout in a `div` and add a `class` or `id` attribute to that `div` that you can use in CSS / jQuery to set the width of the web parts, as an example:

```
<div id="hp-header" class="col-md-12">
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server"
      Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_Header%>" ID="Header">
        <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
    </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
```

You can use the CSS `:nth-child`selector to target a specific web part.